# Is there a way to move entire row in MS Word tables?

Tags: user-interface, ms-word, formatting, row, editor

In many source code editors, you can easily rearrange lines by holding hotkey sequence while pressing arrow keys up and down, which moves lines up or down. Is there a way to do that in tables in MS Word? If yes, will it move color formatting along the row, also?
Right now, I have to cut rows and paste them where I need, using paste special>source formatting option, which glitches and requires 3 additional clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not a question for SO (no programming etc.) this is the answer:

`Alt + Shift + arrow up/down`

This works for any paragraph or table row.